# Detecting if an element is outside of its parent's outer bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a lightbox jQuery plugin and inside the lightbox (image) there are absolutely positioned elements (inside the image).

[image]

These elements are going to be randomly added on top of the red image. Currently, these blue squares will overlap the outer bounds of the red image.

How can I detect this behaviour? The blue will sometimes be hidden and then, on `click`, it will expand over the outer bounds of the red.

Comment: detect it with `if else` :lol

Comment: Do you need to detect at all b/c you say that clicking on the blue box will allow it to overflow. Therefore I would use css and overflow:hidden on the red box and when the user clicks on a blue box, apply overflow:visible; Not sure however what would trigger it to go back to overflow:hidden.

Comment: How are the blue elements positioned to begin with, and are they added as children of the red element, or as siblings?

Comment: If you have the information ahead of time (i.e. width & height of both child & parent) it may be worth placing a constraint on where the child element can be randomly placed within the parent element. Detecting position and adjusting for a bad random placement with another random placement will be more expensive than computing the constraints ahead of time and avoiding overlap detection altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the bounding box of each element and do a quick comparison of the edges to detect if it's inside or outside the element.

```js
var isItIn = function(parent, child) {
  var box1coords = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  var box2coords = child.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (
    box2coords.top < box1coords.top || 
    box2coords.right > box1coords.right ||
    box2coords.bottom > box1coords.bottom || 
    box2coords.left < box1coords.left) {

    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
  
}

console.log(isItIn(document.querySelector('.box1'), document.querySelector('.box2')));

console.log(isItIn(document.querySelector('.box1'), document.querySelector('.box3')));
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
  
}

.box3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 150px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://api.jquery.com/position/

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of
>   an element (specifically its margin box) relative to the offset parent
>   (specifically its padding box, which excludes margins and borders).

However, this doesn't work for hidden elements. (It is not quite clear when you need to detect the overlap).

If the blue elements are not children of the blue, you can use https://api.jquery.com/offset/ instead.

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an
>   element (specifically its border box, which excludes margins) relative
>   to the document.